# Customizing Firefox keyboard shortcuts

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I customize the [keyboard shortcuts on Firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts) 3.6.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keyconfig](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Keyconfig_extension) will allow this.