# How to prevent Firefox keyboard shortcuts from interfering with Unicode input?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

**Operating System:** Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

**Browser:** Firefox Quantum 60.0 (64-bit)

I usually use the [Alt + Numpad plus - Unicode](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/08/17/three-ways-to-enter-unicode-characters-in-windows/) method to enter Unicode characters. But this method doesn't always work in Firefox. Sometimes the hex code I need to type overlaps with some Firefox shortcut key. For example, I can't introduce the letter **ð** because its hex code is **00F0** and when I get to the **F**, Firefox interprets the fact that both **Alt** and **F** are being pressed as a command to open the **File** menu.

The following Firefox keyboard shortcuts interfere with my typing:

- **Alt** + **Numpad 2** and **Alt** + **B** open the Bookmark menu
- **Alt** + **Numpad 5** and **Alt** + **E** open the Edit menu
- **Alt** + **Numpad 6** and **Alt** + **F** open the File menu
- **Alt** + **D** selects the address bar

How do I get around these Firefox hotkeys so I can enter any Unicode character I want?

This is what I have tried and found that it doesn't work:

- [How to disable all keyboard shortcuts for Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/425610/how-to-disable-all-keyboard-shortcuts-for-firefox)
- [Customizing Firefox keyboard shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/210857/customizing-firefox-keyboard-shortcuts)
- [Key config](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/key-config/)

**EDIT:** I am interested in a solution that does not require [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) or other third party software.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the following add-on, [Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts) for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys/?src=search) and disabled the unwanted shortcuts like this:

[image: Shortkeys add-on Settings]

I made sure each shortcut I wanted disabled had the same settings, like this:

[image: Shortkeys add-on Settings]

Although this partial solution is keyboard layout independent and allows me to enter many characters that were impossible before I installed the add-on, it has some limitations. For example, I can enter the letters **Ð** (`U-00D0`) and **ð** (`U-00F0`) by using the [input method](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/08/17/three-ways-to-enter-unicode-characters-in-windows/) described in the question but for some odd reason I can't enter **Ý** (`U-00DD`), **ý** (`U-00FD`), **Þ** (`U-00DE`), **þ** (`U+00FE`), **Æ** (`U+00C6`), **æ** (`U+00E6`), **Ö** (`U+00D6`), **ö** (`U+00F6`). It seems that if the last key pressed before the release of the **Alt** key is one of the shortcut keys, the Shortkeys add-on intercepts that and interferes with the input method.

**EDIT:** The [Easy Unicode Input](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-unicode-input/?src=search) Firefox add-on seems to be the best solution so far. All I have to do now is press **Ctrl**+**'** to activate the Unicode Input Mode and then type code of the character I want. For example, to enter the character **Ö**, I press and hold **Ctrl** hit **'** release **Ctrl** and then type 00d6. The drawback of this method is that it cannot be used in the **Find on this page** search field, or in the **Address Bar**, or in the **Search Bar**.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the solution to your problem is [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com). You can write a simple script that remaps any key combo of your choosing to any key on your keyboard. So if ALT+Numpad2 interferes with a preset shortcut in firefox, you can change it so that instead Shift+Numpad2 performs your desired action instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I know about AutoHotkey. I have edited my question to reflect the fact that I don't want a solution based on AutoHotkey or other 3rd party software.

Comment: No worries, i up-voted your question seeing as i have helped you further refine it to something more specific to your needs.